# Retrieving instances from random forest result

Tags: r, random-forest, feature-selection

I am modifying the features in my random forest model, somehow I found a large amount of instances are misclassified, how can I find out the userid of those misclassified cases?

```
  fit1 <- cforest((b == 'three')~   affect+ certain+ negemo+ future+swear+sad
            +negate+ppron+sexual+death + filler+leisure + conj+ funct + i
            +future + past + bio + body+cause + cogmech + death +
            discrep + future +incl + motion + quant + sad + tentat + excl+insight +percept +posemo
            +ppron +quant + relativ + space + article
            , data = trainset1, 
            controls=cforest_unbiased(ntree=1000, mtry= 1))

 table1 <- table(predict(fit1, OOB=TRUE, type = 'response') > 0.5, trainset1$b == 'three')
```

result

```
        FALSE TRUE
 FALSE   213  200
 TRUE    821 1121
```

As the result has shown, 821 of other classes are misclassified as "three",  how can I retrieve these 821 cases according to userid so that I can compare their features. Thank you.

Comment: which package `cforest` belongs to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want to take some of the code that is already being used to create that table and use it to pick out the rows that are being put into the bottom left of the table.

So here's the code that is making your table work:

```
predict(fit1, OOB=TRUE, type = 'response') > 0.5, trainset1$b == 'three'
```

If you run the first part of that, you'll get a vector of all the predictions:

```
p<-predict(fit1, OOB=TRUE, type = 'response')
```

If you then apply the >0.5 threshold, you'll get a vector of TRUE and FALSE that represents whether your prediction is above or below that threshold:

```
tf<- p>0.5
```

Now, the last part is providing another vector of TRUE and FALSE values, trainset1$b=="three". And what you want to know is which rows that are classified as "three" (I'm thinking that's a TRUE in tf i.e. p>0.5) but are not actually of class "three" (a FALSE from the question trainset1$b=="three"). To work this out you want all rows where tf ==TRUE AND trainset1$b !="three":

```
newdata<- trainset1[tf==TRUE & trainset1$b!="three",]
```

Just double check that nrow(newdata) is 821.